# validar un número decimal en un request laravel

Tags: php, laravel, regex

Necesito validar un número que debe cumplir con las siguientes reglas:

1. Debe ser mayor que cero
2. debe permitir solo dos lugares decimales
3. debe tener un máximo de 15 caracteres

para esto probé la siguiente regla de validación:

```
'required|numeric|max:15|gt:0|regex:/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/'
```

pero no funciona para mí, alguna idea de qué cambios puedo hacer o cómo deberían verse mis reglas de validación

Answer (score 0):

Si solo lo como 'required' y number en tu validacion (no se si estas usando un FromRequest), y en el html colocas Input type="number" Step=".01"

Espero te sirva

Comment: Esto cubre la cantidad de cifras y el tema de los decimales?